# How to specify Person Function for Rollbar logger in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony4, monolog, rollbar

In configuring the Rollbar Monolog configuration, one of the options that can be set is the `person_fn` function. That configuration Rollbar is expecting to be some sort of "callable", which when called will return information about the user.

In order to get the information about the current user, that method is going to need the Session handler, to get the currently-logged-in user. I can write a service that does that:

```
<?php
class UserService {
  private $session;

  public function __construct(SessionInterface $session) {
    $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function RollbarUserFn() {
    $u = $this->session->get('current_user');
    return array(
      'id' => $u['id'],
      'username' => $u['username']
    ); 
  }
}
```

Now, if just using `call_user_func`, the `RollbarUserFn` method is not static (since it has a dependency), so cannot use `"UserService::RollbarUserFn"` (a string), but rather instantiate it and pass the object in:

```
$us = new UserService($sessionInterface);
call_user_func(array($us, 'RollbarUserFn'));
```

But how can I do that equivalent in the config YAML file? I've tried something like:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    rollbar:
      type: rollbar
      token: '123123123'
      config:
        environment: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
        person_fn: [ '@UserService', 'RollbarUserFn' ]
```

But that throws an error that the `person_fn` config node is expected to be a Scalar, not an array

Comment: Hi there - The best way to get an answer to your question is to email support@rollbar.com.  That'll get you directly in touch w/ the developers who maintain the Rollbar SDKs.

Comment: Thanks, @JesseGibbs, but the issue here isn't with Rollbar and its SDKs, but rather with Symfony and its means of describing "Services" that seems to be the sticking point.

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate `RollbarHandlerFactory` from `rollbar/rollbar-php-symfony-bundle` like that:

```
#config/services_prod.yaml

services:
  App\Service\RollbarHandlerFactory:
    decorates: Rollbar\Symfony\RollbarBundle\Factories\RollbarHandlerFactory
    arguments:
      - '@service_container'
      - ['password', 'plainPassword', 'proxyInitialized', 'proxyInitializer', 'photo']
```

and reconfigure logger

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Rollbar\Rollbar;
use Rollbar\Symfony\RollbarBundle\Factories\RollbarHandlerFactory as BaseFactory;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class RollbarHandlerFactory extends BaseFactory
{
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, array $scrubFields = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($container);

        Rollbar::logger()->configure([
            'person_fn' => function () use ($container, $scrubFields) {
                try {
                    $token = $container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

                    if ($token) {
                        /** @var \App\Model\User $user */
                        $user = $token->getUser();
                        $serializer = $container->get('serializer');
                        $person = \json_decode($serializer->serialize($user, 'json'), true);

                        foreach ($scrubFields as $field) {
                            unset($person[$field]);
                        }

                        $person['id'] = $user->getEmail();

                        return $person;
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```